# Can I install OS X Mountain Lion on my Mac Mini?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, osx-mountain-lion

My Mac Mini configuration is

```
Model Name: Mac mini
  Model Identifier: Macmini3,1
  Processor Name:   Intel Core 2 Duo
  Processor Speed:  2.26 GHz
  Number Of Processors: 1
  Total Number Of Cores:    2
  L2 Cache: 3 MB
  Memory:   2 GB    

System Version: Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Kernel Version: Darwin 10.8.0
```

Is it possible to install Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion on my Mac? If possible, what is the procedure for installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out whether your Mac supports a certain version of OS X, you can [check Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_mini).

For your model, the `Macmini3,1`, the maximum supported operating system is Mountain Lion (10.8). The previous Mac Mini models however only support up to Lion (10.7).

To install OS X Mountain Lion, simply [open the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-mountain-lion/id537386512?ls=1&mt=12), buy it from there, download and install.